# Android image is not uploading in ftp server

Tags: java, android, ftp

Uploading image from android phone to Ftp server, It is not uploading my image into Ftp server it shows windows leaked error,it shows sdcard path but the image is not uploading into the ftp folder can anyone please help me.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    btnSetImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);
    upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload_btn);

    btnSetImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectImage();
        }
    });
    upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Uploading",
                        "Please wait...", true);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                //File f = new File("file:///android_asset/launcher.png");
                // Log.i("do in image ", tempPath);
                 new doFileUpload().execute(); 

            }
    });

}
class doFileUpload extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
   // Log.i("do in image ", path);

    String hostName = "xxxxx";
        String username = "dsdadg";
        String password = "adasdh";

        InputStream in = null;
        protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) {
            String loc = tempPath.toString();

             Log.i("location in async ", loc);
        try {
            FTPClient  ftp = new FTPClient();
            ftp.connect(hostName);
            ftp.login(username, password);

            ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/ftp/gallery/");  // FTP folder path

            int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
            System.out.println("Received Reply from FTP Connection:" + reply);

            if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
                System.out.println("Connected Success");
            }
            File f1 = new File("/sdcard/Image/003.JPG");

            in = new FileInputStream(f1);


            ftp.storeFile("/ftp/gallery/", in);
            ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            System.out.println("SUCCESS");

            ftp.logout();
            ftp.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return hostName;            
    }
}
private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
            "Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File f = new File(android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                        SELECT_FILE);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }               
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {
                Bitmap bm;
                BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                        btmapOptions);

                // bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 70, 70, true);
                ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);

            path = android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator
                        + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                f.delete();
                OutputStream fOut = null;
                File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System
                        .currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                try {
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

             tempPath = getPath(selectedImageUri, MainActivity.this);
            Log.i("temporary path", tempPath);
            Bitmap bm;
            BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempPath, btmapOptions);
            ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }
    }
        //return urlPosting;
}

public String getPath(Uri uri, Activity activity) {
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = activity
            .managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

}
```